# Why we require Statement in java.sql.* package

Tags: jdbc

A general question, but I am not able to find answer for this: if PreparedStatement can run even static sqls, why we need statement in java.sql.*

EDIT:
Thanks Mat

but my concern is why one would use Statement rather than using PreparedStatement, in other words where Statement supersedes PreparedStatement

Note: My understanding is- one can use Statement for static queries nor fired frequently, rather than the PreparedStatement, which is used in cases of frequent queries(reason: performance because of pre-compilation of SQL)

Comment: Did you notice PreparedStatement extends Statement, and that's not the only one that extends it?

Answer (score 0):

In general, PreparedStatement will have a better performance, when you have the same query in your code because it make cache of query.

But if in your application, if the frequency of the same query is very less, then preparedstatement will not improve any performance. Here you should use statement, which is the primary choice for your jdbc based development codebase.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , but how you can say: Statement is the primary choice for your jdbc based development codebase. Asking this, as this will help me to find answers myself to these type of questions( hope you dont say oracle docs/google search)

Comment: Because for JDBC using the default choice is Statement. We willt use callablestatement when we use stored procedure, we will use preparedstatement when we can have a chance to save the execution plan of a query and give the result to the user without need of further execution plan. That will happen only the whole query statement is same as previous one. But this happens in some cases in an application. In most cases we use statement as the default case, because the queries are different for most of the cases.